# Need help using eval and quote funct

Tags: lisp, eval, quote

My code looks like this:

```
 (eval `(setf (fdefinition name-funct)(lambda ............)))
```

To create my funct I have used the quote... but name-funct is a variable... How can I get say to the interprets if I use the quote? Does exist a way to do what I want?

*** EDIT ***

with comma I have this situation

```
Error: The variable REAL-NAME is unbound.
```

So I need that the contens of name-funct must be the name of my lambda that I created. But with the comma operator that Greg Hewgill suggest to me Lisp looks for the content of name-funct that is real-name like another variable.

Comment: What do you want to do? What is `real-name`? Why do you think you need `eval`?

Comment: I've read the sequence of questions you've asked here recently, and my impression is your questions are becoming more and more bizarre. I suggest you should ask a question about the right approach for what you're trying to achieve in general, because I strongly doubt you're even remotely on the right track now.

Comment: why? this is my problem!! can you help me? maybe by rewrite in some different way what I'm tryng to do?

Comment: marchetto91 This is your immediate problem. I suspect your general problem is that you're approaching a problem from entirely the wrong direction and if you can ask about ways of accomplishing your final goal, rather than trying to fix the step you're trying to take right now, we may be able to guide you along a less painful road. You say "maybe by rewrite in some different way what I'm tryng to do" and all we can say is "we don't *know* what you're trying to achieve, without knowing that all we can say is that what you're trying to do right now looks strange and bizarre".

Comment: I need to do that to defun on the go one new function to do (REAL-NAME-OF-MY-FUNCT object @args)

Comment: This is way I need to rename my lambda with a name-funct that is a variable that contains the real name of my funct that I wan't to define

Comment: It's not clear at all what you need the `eval` and backquote for. Just use the `setf` directly. If you're using the backquote to build your lambda function from s-expressions, consider composing it from lambdas instead, or at least wrap the `eval` and backquote directly around the `lambda` instead of the `setf`.

Comment: @Rörd or at least wrap the eval and backquote directly around the lambda instead of the setf.... HOW??? cnq you show me??

Comment: What I meant is just this: `(setf (fdefinition name-funct) (eval \`(lambda ............)))`

Comment: thank you! nice it works! and if I try (fdefinition 'realname) I get to the output (LAMBDA ....) but when I try to call it (realname args) I get  Segmentation violation(11) [code 0] at 8B238060 why this error?

Comment: Wow, a segmentation fault shouldn't be possible in Lisp unless you've explicitly decreased the safety level (i.e. made a `(optimize (safety 0))` declaration). Which Lisp implementation are you using?

Comment: O_O I don't use (optimize (safety 0)) I'm using Common Lisp in Lispworks

Answer (score 1):

Use the comma:

```
(eval `(setf (fdefinition ,name-funct)(lambda ............))
```

Comment: seems it doesn't work. If I i use the 'name-funct I can do this (name-funct args) and works but if I use the ,name-funct If I do (real-name-of-my-funct args) I get this error Undefined operator NAME-FUNCT

Comment: I use LipsWorks and Common Lisp

Comment: (fdefinition 'real-name)

Error: Undefined function REAL-NAME in form (SYMBOL-FUNCTION TALK).

Comment: I edit my answer, comma works but it isn't what I looking for

Comment: (fdefinition 'real-name-funct) show me errors.. does there is a way to write what I want do to in a better way? maybe using to differents method?